# Relating coefficients in $\sum_1^\infty\log(1-x_i) = \log(y)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Suppose that we have the following relationship:

$\sum_1^\infty\log(1-x_i) = \log(y)$

where $y\in(0,1)$ and $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ $\subset(0,1)$ is a sequence. If we want the find the elements of $(x_i)$, would we do a Taylor series expansion for $\log(1-x_i)$ and $\log(y)$?

Could we construct what $(x_i)$ will look like from the above equality?

Comment: Think of it as an equation system: you know *one* value ($\log(y)$) and you have an *infinite* number of unknowns $x_i$ to be determined from this *one* equation. At best we can determine *one* value as a function of the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any convergent series such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n=S$ with $s_n<0$. Define $x_n=1-e^{s_n}$ and $y=e^S$. It is easy to verify that this choice satisfies the relationship $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log(1-x_n)=\log y$.

Comment: To confirm, do you mean that $s_n<0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: In any case, $s_n\to 0$ since the series is convergent. But since $x_i\in(0,1)$, $s_n<0$ for each $n$.

Comment: Brillante answer (+1).

Comment: I apologize for asking (it is likely elementary) but how did you verify the choice above? Is this something that we learned in calculus 2 that I forgot?

Comment: No need to apologize. See that if $1-e^{s_n}$ is inside $(0,1)$, then $e^{s_n}$ should be smaller that $1$ and this is only possible if $s_n<0$.